# const char* pointing to an array of char on the stack

Tags: c++, c

I wrote this piece of code

```
int main()
{
    char a[] = "ABCD";
    const char* b = a;
    a[1] = 'E';
    printf("%s %s", a, b);
    getchar();
}
```

The code compiled and ran successfully.

How am I able to access the memory pointed by 'const char* b' and modify it ? Does it mean that for a shared memory const definition does not matter ?

Thank you

Comment: This works because the object pointed at by `b` isn't `const` itself. But had you tried the following: `*(b+1) = 'E';` instead,  you would have gotten a compiler error message, such as: `error: read-only variable is not assignable` (clang). You can access it, but can't modify it through `b`.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is here.  You declared `b` as const, not `a`, and you're accessing the array using `a`, not `b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const char* b` means that you cannot modify the thing `b` points to *through* `b`. But you can modify it through some other means, provided the thing isn't `const` in the first place<sup>*</sup>.

Here is a simplified example:

```
int a = 0;
const int* p = &a;
a = 42;  // OK! a is not const.
*p = 43; // ERROR! Cannot modify a through p.

const int b = 0;
p = &b;
b = 43;  // ERROR! b is const.
```

---

<sup>* This holds for C++. The details may be slightly different in C</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Declaration of `b` with type `const char *` means that you cannot modify data using pointer `b` itself, it does not affect memory `b` points to in any sense.

Answer (score 2):

`char * p`
`p` is a non-constant pointing to a non-constant character. We can change the character value using `p`, and change `p` to point at another character.

`char const * p`
`const char * p`
`p` is a non-constant pointer to a constant character. We can't change the character value using `p`, but can change `p` to point at another character.

`char * const p`
`p` is a constant pointer to a non-constant character. We can change the character value using `p`, but can't change `p` to point at another character.

`char const * const p`
`const char * const p`
`p` is a constant pointer to a constant character. We can't change the character value using `p`, or change `p` to point at another character.

In your question, `a` and `b` point at the same memory. `b` is declared as `const char *`, so it is a non-constant pointer to a constant character. That doesn't mean that anybody else can't modify the character. Only that you can't modify the character using `b`.

Answer (score 1):

`const char * b` just means that you cannot modify what `b` points to ... through `b`.  The place it points to is an ordinary memory location, though, and can be modified by anything else that points to it.

The contract represented by `const` is only valid with respect to the variable or method the const is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

> How am I able to access the memory pointed by `'const char* b'` and modify it ?

You are able to access memory pointed to by `b` regardless of whether it is declared as

```
const char* b;
```

or

```
char* b;
```

You won't be able to modify the value through `b`. The following is an error:

```
b[1] = 'E';
```

> Does it mean that for a shared memory const definition does not matter ?

The `const` qualifier matters -- whether it is shared memory or not. Had you used:

```
const char a[] = "ABCD";
const char* b = a;
```

the following will be an error too.

```
a[1] = 'E';
```